# In 14.04 Gnome Classic, how to add icons to panel?

Tags: 14.04, panel, ubuntu-gnome

I am unable to add program icons to the top panel in Gnome Classic. I have tried holding the alt and/or the meta key and right clicking, but get no response. I was able to do this in 12.04.

Do I need to learn how to do it from a command line?

Comment: Search for the applications then drag it over to your panel. Tell if this works.

Comment: Thanks King, but no, that doesn’t work either.

Answer (score 5):

To add icons or app launcher on panel key combination is `windows button + Alt + Right Click`. A drop down will appear with options to Add to Panel, Properties, Add panel etc.

Answer (score 1):

Install `gnome-session-flashback`.

Using either `synaptic` or type in the terminal `sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback`

Besides install `Metacity`. Now `log-out` and choose from the `log-in` menu a flashback version, and you can add launchers to the menu bar by alt-right click.

Answer (score 0):

Once the gnome-session-flashback is installed and you log out and log in again, not only you can ALT-right click on the top panel (taskbar), you can drag and drop the desired apps from Application to the top panel.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately I am no longer using Gnome (or linux), and cannot check your suggestion.

Comment: @JimH, thank you for your reply. Are you using Apple  OSX or Windows now?

Comment: I left Linux primarily because I wanted to use Adobe InDesign  which meant Windows or Apple. I was also tired of being my own systems administrator. But although MacOS is based on Linix, it isn't Linux—alas! For example, it doesn't differentiate between upper and lower case in filenames, something Linus Torvalds called stupid. When I am finished with InDesign I will return to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

`Super` + `Right Click` on the panel should work. Tested in 2020.

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Flashback#Configuration