# In Gnome Classic, how to add icons to panel?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, panel

In question [In 14.04 Gnome Classic, how to add icons to panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515658/in-14-04-gnome-classic-how-to-add-icons-to-panel/564924#564924) the top answer tells me to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⊞ Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd>. I have an IBM keyboard from 1984 without a <kbd>⊞ Windows</kbd> key. How do I add an icon to the panel?